# Extract cookie value off Header request

Tags: php, cookies, websocket

In PHP, I access the header cookies with: `$cookie = $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie')`. This gives me an array, of length `1`, that contain one string. The string 'describes' the website cookies of the `$conn` (the user). This is the header:

```
GET /sample_page.html HTTP/2.0
Host: www.example.org
Cookie: yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry
```

And as expected, when I try to access the `$cookie[0]` value in my code I get the string: `"yummy_cookie=choco; tasty_cookie=strawberry"`.

I want to access easily the value of the first cookie (indexed by `yummy_cookie`), but the format of the string makes it difficult, because I can't guarantee that I'll always want to access the first cookie.
Is there any way to make it easy?

I use `Ratchet PHP Websocket`, and in the websocket server I try to access a specific cookie value of specific user (`$conn`):

```
<?php
namespace dealspace_websocket;
use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        //$this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage;
        $this->clients = [];
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $cookiesArray = $conn->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie');

    }
}
```

Comment: there is an function getCookies which returns associative array of allcookies.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I don't have access to the cookies in this case. My only access is via `getHeader('cookie')`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Same as I said above..

Comment: please extend your question with information about used framework and with code example.

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I edited. You can see now why I can't access neither `gotCookies` and `$_COOKIES`..

Comment: Did you look into SessionProvider of the framework? You can see that author of framework parses cookies manually. So there is no alternative and you need to parse it yourself. Not a big deal really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code to access cookie indexed by `PHPSESSID` (any other index can be also used..):

```
$cookiesArray = explode('; ', $from->httpRequest->getHeader('Cookie')[0]);
foreach($cookiesArray as $cookie):
    if(strpos($cookie, "PHPSESSID=") == 0):
        $sessid = explode('=', $cookie)[1];
        break;
    endif;
endforeach;
```